# Translating vbscript to c#

Tags: c#

Can you please help translate this statement to c#

```
if not ((sTieTocpi = "Y") or (sTieTocpi = "N")) then ...
```

I am reading an excel file and this is a validation. The field can only contain
Y or N and not any other letter. Y or N is valid but other letters are not valid.
How do I write this in C#?

Comment: Here is a hint, `not` becomes `!`, `=` becomes `==` and `or` becomes `||`.

Comment: Use a boolean variable.

Comment: Now you have a chamelion question - Ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!((sTieTocpi == "Y") || (sTieTocpi == "N")))
{
     //Then
}
```

In C# `or` becomes `||`, `=` (used for comparison, not assignment) becomes `==`. By surrounding the entire statement and inserting the `!` operator, the boolean value is inverted.

Answer (score 5):

You can translate this as:

```
if (!((sTieTocpi == "Y") || (sTieTocpi == "N")))
{
    // ...
```

That being said, using a variable would make this more readable:

```
bool isYOrN = sTieTocpi == "Y" || sTieTocpi == "N";
if (!isYOrN)
{
   //...
```

Comment: What is that syntax? Usually i see `variable = this == that ? true case : false case`. Is it equivalent to that?

Comment: @tnw This just assigns a boolean directly.  The `||` operator returns a boolean directly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

Comment: Aha! I was reading that page and didn't quite get how it tied in here, now I see. Very cool. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((sTieTocpi != "Y") && (sTieTocpi != "N"))
{

}
```

Comment: @user1 - yes, thanks, updated answer. Typed too quickly. :-)

Comment: Your parens are off a bit.

Comment: @Servy - looks like someone edited it for me, thanks for the heads up. :-)

Comment: The inner parens are now redundant and can just be removed, but yeah, it's now no longer wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sTieTocpi = "Y";
if(!((sTieTocpi == "Y") || (sTieTocpi == "N"))){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (sTieTocpi != "Y" && sTieTocpi != "N")
 {
   //Do things
 }
```

Are lowercase values allowed?

edit; woops :)

Comment: `||` needs to be `&&` if you are going to invert the logic. otherwise you just let everything in. Think of the old riddle, "I have two coins in my hand totaling 30 cents and one of them is not a quarter", You have a nickel and a quarter, because a nickle is not a quarter.

Comment: Thanks Scott! Long day at work, wasn't thinking.